# Sound only works via bluetooth 18.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, 18.10

My laptop was totally fine until I wanted to try some Bluetooth speaker I have, since then I can't have sound through the laptop speaker or anything connected to the mini-plug connector. I tried several things, re installing `pulseaudio` `alsa-base`, deleting and `./config/pulse` and restart. I don't know what else to do. I know the speakers work because I have the laptop on dual boot and they work just fine on windows.

Answer (score 0):

Well, After trying pretty much everything there was out there and without much success; I upgraded to 19.04, and sounds works through speakers. Although I have to say I'm terrified of using my laptop again with any Bluetooth devices. Which is a shame. Whatever it was I feel it should be fixable without having to upgrade.